# C - sleep() in threads gives problems

Tags: c, pthreads

sleep() function gives me problem in a program.
I have declared only one mutex, one condition variable and one global variable:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t something1;
int protected = 1;
```

After initializing them, and creating the 2 threads inside the main with `pthread_create`, i write this:

```
void *Thread(void *arg)
{
        while(1){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

                while(protected == 0){
                        pthread_cond_wait(&something1, &mutex);
                }
                printf("aaa");

                sleep(2);

                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *Thread2(void *arg){
        while(1){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

                while(protected == 1){
                        pthread_cond_wait(&something1, &mutex);
                }

                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

This should just print **"aaa"** in loop forever, and this works if I remove the `sleep(2)`.
If I leave it, the program starts, stays alive, but it prints nothing.
Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: what's the difference between `pthread_mutex_lock` and `DBGpthread_mutex_lock` and should you be mixing them? Where's `pthread_cond_signal`? Where is `protected` changed?

Comment: I edited it. It is just a module that i use, nothing changes.

Comment: how about getting the `sleep()` out of your critical section?

Comment: Tried it, same problem.

Comment: What if you add a `fflush(stdout);` after the printf?

Comment: With fflush or \n in the printf it works fine! Solved.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` is line buffered, meaning it won't flush the buffer to screen until it reaches a newline `"\n"`, or when the buffer is full. When you don't sleep, the buffer fills up quickly and prints to screen when it gets full, but when you do sleep it will take a long time for the buffer to fill, and so you never see anything on screen.  Try changing that to `printf("aaa\n");`, or add an `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`.  See more information here: [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: That's correct, with fflush or \n in the printf everything works fine. Thank you, this is very helpful even for my studies.